Replace Class Function using subhook? (pass Class Function as Pointer)
I'm attempting to replace a C++ class function using the subhook library.
I'm able to replace a standalone function using subhook, as in the following example:
#include <iostream>
#include "subhook/subhook.h"

std::string TestFx() {return "TEST";}
std::string ReplaceFx() {return "REPLACED";}

subhook_t testHook;
subhook_flags_t testHookFlags;

int main() 
{
    std::cout << "Normal: " << TestFx() << "\n";
    
    testHook = subhook_new(&TestFx, &ReplaceFx, testHookFlags);
    subhook_install(testHook);
    std::cout << "Replaced: " << TestFx() << "\n";

    subhook_remove(testHook);
    std::cout << "Reverted: " << TestFx() << "\n";

    return 0;
}

Where I simply replace TestFx with ReplaceFx, and works without issues:
Normal: TEST
Replaced: REPLACED
Reverted: TEST

However, attempting to replace a class function is proving more difficult. It appears that I cannot simply supply a class function to the subhook_install function in the same manner.
Attempting the following example:
#include <iostream>
#include "subhook/subhook.h"

class TestClass
{
public:
    std::string TestFx() {return "TEST";}
};

std::string ReplaceFx() {return "REPLACED";}

subhook_t testHook;
subhook_flags_t testHookFlags;

int main() 
{
    TestClass* tc = new TestClass();
    std::cout << "Normal: " << tc->TestFx() << "\n";
    
    testHook = subhook_new(&TestClass::TestFx, &ReplaceFx, testHookFlags);
    subhook_install(testHook);
    std::cout << "Replaced: " << tc->TestFx() << "\n";

    subhook_remove(testHook);
    std::cout << "Reverted: " << tc->TestFx() << "\n";
    delete tc;

    return 0;
}

Results in:

E0167 argument of type "std::string (TestClass::*)()" is incompatible with parameter of type "void *"

Attempting to use reinterpret_cast to typecast TestClass::TestFx to void* results in:

E0171 invalid type conversion

As far as I understand, the reason for these errors is because pointers to class functions are often larger than pointers to standalone functions, hence they often times don't fit in a void* type.
However, it doesn't appear that subhook_install accepts anything other than void*, so I'm a bit confused as to how one would replace a class function using this method.
What is the proper way to replace a class function using the subhook library? Are there perhaps other similar libraries that can accomplish the task?
Thanks for reading my post, any guidance is appreciated.

You can't call a non-static class member function like that. You need an object.

@sweenish I do have an object, it's the local variable tc. I call it with tc->TestFx().

subhook_new(&TestClass::TestFx, &ReplaceFx, testHookFlags); Where's that tc at? Or is the expectation that you'll "hook" the function for any object?

@sweenish as far as I understand, that is how it's supposed to work, replacing TestClass::TestFx so it changes for all the TestClass objects. Doing tc->TestFx I think is only used for calling the function, not to get a pointer to it. If I do subhook_new(&tc->TestFx, &ReplaceFx, testHookFlags); like you suggest, I get E0300 a pointer to a bound function may only be used to call the function.

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.2.0?topic=only-pointers-members-c

@sweenish hmm, that is very interesting, I didn't know one could create pointers like that. Thanks for sharing. Doing std::string (TestClass::*TestFxPtr)() = &TestClass::TestFx; testHook = subhook_new(&TestFxPtr, &ReplaceFx, testHookFlags); actually gives no errors during compilation, however TestClass::TestFx doesn't appear to get replaced successfully. It still prints TEST after the subhook_install call. I also tried putting the subhook_install call before creating a TestClass object, with the same result.

Use typedef for member functions.

In your last comment, you are sending a pointer to a member function pointer to subhook_new. This isn't going to work.

@TheNomad thanks for sharing that FAQ. I tried adding a typedef declaration before the subhook_new call like this: typedef std::string (TestClass::*TestFxPtr)(); TestFxPtr ptr = &TestClass::TestFx;. However, it unfortunately is still not able to typecast ptr to void*. As a matter of fact, one of the other entries in that FAQ website you shared outright states that converting class function pointers to void* is "illegal": https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members#cant-cvt-memfnptr-to-voidptr. It unfortunately appears that this may not be possible to do using subhook...

I have seen my share of member functions pointers being forcefully converted to global function pointers or to void* at different former jobs so I wanted to share that link to make sure you don't fall into the same trap. If I raised the topic, it'd be shut down in an instant because "it works" so I should drop it. It was impossible for me to explain to older and more experienced (?) colleagues that just because C or C++ lets you do something "exotic" (I am diplomatic), doesn't mean it's not UB (undefined behavior) or that you should do it, even if it seems (as you won't know 100%) to "work".

@TheNomad oh that's interesting, thanks for sharing. That makes total sense, regular class functions (especially virtual ones) usually have more complex pointers that can't be represented with void*. That's unfortunate for me though, as in my specific application I only have absolute pointers that still point to class functions, not their class' virtual tables... Looks like I'm gonna have a find a different library.
